# How to convert QString to QDate in specific format?

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, qdate

I have a `QDateEdit` in my GUI from which I convert the `QDate` to `QString` and add it to my database. The `QString` date is saved in the database in this format: 20/12/2015.

In case a user want to edit the date, then I need to show the date on the `QDateEdit` field on the GUI again. Hence, I need to fetch the database, bring back the date (which is in `QString` format) and convert it to `QDate` back again in order to put it on the `QDateEdit` field on the GUI.

However, I cannot manage to convert that `QString` format (i.e.: 20/12/2015) to `QDate` using the following:

```
QString date_string_on_db = "20/12/2015";
QDate Date;
Date.fromString(date_string_on_db,"dd/MM/YYYY");
```

The `Date` is always returning `invalid`.

what should I do ?

Comment: Try using `dd/MM/yyyy` for the format string.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

First of all, the format string should be `dd/MM/yyyy`. [Qt documentation for the `QDate` class](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdate.html#fromString-1) says that `yyyy` is recognized as a four digit year number.

Second of all, `fromString` is a `static` function that returns a new `QDate`. Currently, the return value of that function is discarded : it is not written back into the `Date` variable, as you might think. The complete correct code should therefore look like this :

```
QString date_string_on_db = "20/12/2015";
QDate Date = QDate::fromString(date_string_on_db,"dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Comment: This worked, but note to the Americans like me that tried copy and paste and it didn't work: it should be "MM/dd/yyyy" for US dates